Login using google not working after deployment
I have a asp.net core MVC web application where I have set-up "login using google" feature. It works perfectly fine in my localhost, however, I'm either getting the infamous "redirect_uri_mismatch" error when I set-up Authorized redirect URIs as https://mywebsitename.co.uk/Authentication/ExternalLoginCallback. On the other hand, I get the option to select an account to sign-in when I set redirect UTI to https://mywebsitename.co.uk/signin-google, but unfortunately the request times out after 60 seconds and I get an unhandled exception.
Details of the unhandled exception -
`TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, bool telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()`
Not sure what am I doing wrong. My AuthenticationController has the standard methods like Login, ExternalLogin and ExternalLoginCallback and most importantly, it does work in localhost. I added some logging and looks like ExternalLoginCallback is never invoked after I give permission to an account to sign in to my website. The URL is like -
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/id?authuser=4&part=...&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow&as=S-...&client_id=....apps.googleusercontent.com&rapt=...and it stops progressing when I click on continue.
Parts of my program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 302768;
});
...
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Authentication/ExternalLogin";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
...
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");
});
..
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
});

If it helps - I'm trying to deploy my website at Ionos shared windows hosting. Suggestions will be much appreciated.
Regards,
SBanik
